# TurnBasedGame with libGDX + Google Play Services

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I'm trying to write a small card game for Android using libgdx framework. My game is turn-based. I wrote to interface with the necessary methods to access the API interface from Google. I faced the problem after I called `Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(gameHelper.getApiClient(), tbmc)` I got the result of the callback. If `initiateMatchResult.getMatch().getData()` is `null` I am initiating games data, and here's the PROBLEM: I don't know how to go back in GameScreen???

This is piece of code in AndroidLauncher:

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer
                .createMatch(gameHelper.getApiClient(), tbmc)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult initiateMatchResult) {
                        if (!initiateMatchResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            gameHelper.showFailureDialog();
                            return;
                        }
                        TurnBasedMatch match = initiateMatchResult.getMatch();

                        if (match.getData() != null) {
                            Log.d("MyLogs", "match: not null");
                        }
                        initGame();
                        myGame.setScreen(myGame);
                    }
                });
```

If just call myGame.setScreen(new GameScreen(myGame)) is the GameScreen displaying is not correct. In GameScreen I have table and images in this table and the images displaying is not correct!!!

This code of my GameScreen

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

final MyGame myGame;
private Stage stage;
private Table table;
private Image card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6;

public GameScreen(MyGame myGame) {
    this.myGame = myGame;

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    card1 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("1.png")));
    card2 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("2.png")));
    card3 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("3.png")));
    card4 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("4.png")));
    card5 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("5.png")));
    card6 = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("6.png")));

    table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.setDebug(true);
    table.add(card1).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).padBottom(10);
    table.add(card2).width(140).height(202).padBottom(10);
    table.add(card3).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).padBottom(10).row();
    table.add(card4).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15);
    table.add(card5).width(140).height(202);
    table.add(card6).width(140).height(202).padLeft(15).padRight(15).row();

    stage.addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    mySkin.dispose();
    dixit.getScreen().dispose();
}
```

SCREENSHOT BELOW

[this screenshot shows how to display images in my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90zEC.png)
Tell me what my mistake and what am I doing wrong? Can anyone advise how best to do otherwise??